# Bootstrap: using less mixins

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

What am I missing here?

**home-page.less**

```
@import (reference) "~bootstrap/less/mixins.less";

.home-page {
    .make-md-column(3,6);
    background: red;
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVeQf.png)

Comment: `mixins.less` requires at least `variables.less` to be imported elsewhere (note that individual Bootstrap `less` files do not import their dependencies on their own). And (sorry for offtopic), please don't use `reference` blindly when not required (and it's *absolutely* redundant when you import mixins or variables) - this only misleads and confuses (and may result in weird hard-to-catch sideeffects).

Comment: I solved the issue by importing variables.less. I also just imported grid.less instead of mixins.less. Now since I'm only using .make-md-column(), is there any way to import only this instead of importing the entire variables.less and grid.less?

Comment: *is there any way to import only this instead of importing the entire variables.less and grid.less?* - which "this"? In general, if a mixin uses variables (and other mixins) defined in other files you have to include (= import) these "other files" (otherwise how would the compiler know what these external variables/mixins are about?)